# composite unique constraint in OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

How do I get JPA to enforce unique values of a composite unique constraint on the `Many` side of a `OneToMany` relationship?

In the code below, I have a `Person` entity that has an internal `id`, and that also has a set of external composite `orgids` which are used to identify the `patient`'s relationship with other organizations.  These external composite ids consist of a `root` component which identifies a specific `organization`, and an `extension` component, which identifies the `person` within the specific `organization` identified by the `root`.  Therefore, the combination of `root`/`extension` must be unique in the set of `orgids` that is associated with each `person`.  How can I set the code up to accomplish this?

The code below keeps trying to insert redundant `root`/`extension` values in the `person_org_id table`, though the MySQL database rejects these insert attempts due to the Unique constraint in the DDL below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "person")
    private Set<PersonID> orgids;

    //other properties, then 
    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "person_org_id",
uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id_root", "id_extension"})})
public class PersonID {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_root")
    private Organization org;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="id_extension")
    private String orgpersonid;

    //getters and setters
}


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person(
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY 
  # , other fields
)engine=InnoDB;SHOW WARNINGS;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person_org_id(
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  person_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  id_root varchar(100),
  id_extension varchar(100),
  CONSTRAINT UniqueRootExtKey UNIQUE (id_root, id_extension),
  FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_root) REFERENCES organization(root)
)engine=InnoDB;SHOW WARNINGS;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS organization(
  root varchar(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(200)
)engine=InnoDB;SHOW WARNINGS;
```

This is in a spring mvc app using hibernate with jpa.

Comment: I admit my JPA is a bit rusty (we use nothing but JDBC `CallableStatement`s against Stored Procedures in my current long term project), but wouldn't you want a `OneToOne` relationship here?  Maybe I'm just misreading the question, though.

Comment: @Powerlord Would a `Set` of `orgids` still be allowed in a `OneToOne` relationship?  The `person` will have multiple entries in its `orgids` set, but each member of the `orgids` set must be a unique combination of `root/extension`, to reflect multiple different `organizations` each having its own unique composite identifier for the same `person`.

Answer (score 1):

In essence, the PersonID table is not an entity in its own right, but a linking table between the Person and the Organization. You could map this association as a Map in Hibernate/JPA, using (on the person side) the Organization as the key and the extension as value. (You could also map on Organization side with extension as key)

It would be hard to maintain the PK on the PersonID table, though. This field seems to be redundant, however. You could remove it and add the constraints normally used on a Map-mapped table.

In your case, I would create a class structure where person has Map<Organization,String>. This would be mapped as @ElementCollection with @CollectionTable for the PersonID table and @MapKeyJoinColumn with reference to Organization table. This way the PersonID would not have a generated ID column. The PK would be a constraint on both FK columns to Person and Organization. You could add unique constraint on Fk to Organization and extension column to ensure no duplicate ids.

Alternatively you could maintain the PersonID as entity, which are stored in the map and use bidirectional association back to Person and map MapKey both on the Map<Organization,PersonID> and the PersonID.organization property. But then you would have to be very sure which side is read-write (in control) and which side is readonly (reverse). Unnecessarily more complex.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question.  I do not understand what you are suggesting.  Are you willing to post suggested code?  That would help me wrap my head around your idea.

Comment: See section 7.2.2.2 here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html and read my edit.

Comment: Thank you, and +1 for taking the time to start to elaborate.  I looked at example 7.11 in section 7.2.2.2 in the link you sent, but I am not able to see specifically how to change my code.  These concepts are hard to me, and the answer does not come intuitively yet. Are you willing to show me how to fix my code specifically?  That would help me understand the concepts.